# Displaying muliple lines of text in a figure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, blackjack

I am doing a project where in MATLAB I'm simulating blackjack dealer hand possibilities from one deck and the card is replaced every time. I have everything done and the code is hunky dory, but what I'm trying to do is display some values.

I learned about the `text()` command and am able to output the simplest thing, which is the probability of the dealer busting. Here's my code for this.

```
str = sprintf('The Probability of the Dealer Busting is: %1.4f',BustProb);
figure('Color','white', 'Menu','none')
text(0.5, 0.5, str,'FontSize',12, 'Color','k', ...
    'HorizontalAlignment','Center', 'VerticalAlignment','Middle')
axis off
```

This displays just fine. All in all, I have 39 things to display and it's split into four sets. One set is a 1x26 matrix, one is a 1x11 matric and the other two are just variables. I'd like to be able to display all these values in one window instead of writing them all out. Just to learn about it. Can anyone give some tips on how I could acheive this?

Thanks

Comment: What format do you want your output to be in? It seems like, based on what you're describing, a figure might not be the best place. Perhaps an Excel file?

Comment: You can write multiple lines of text to a figure with one command, btw, like e.g. `text(0.5, 0.5, {'Line 1', 'Line 2', 'Line 3'});`

Comment: Format is not important. I suppose I could write to an excel file, I have done that before. I would just like a figure because I can save them as pictures and merge it into one file and print it all at once. Thank you for the tips as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the `text` function directly with row vectors of cells:

```
mat_1 = {
    'Line A-0';
    'Line A-1';
    'Line A-2';
    'Line A-3';
    'Line A-4';
    'Line A-5';
    'Line A-6';
    'Line A-7';
    'Line A-8';
    'Line A-9'
};

mat_2 = {
    'Line B-0';
    'Line B-1';
    'Line B-2';
    'Line B-3';
    'Line B-4';
    'Line B-5';
    'Line B-6';
    'Line B-7';
    'Line B-8';
    'Line B-9'
};

figure('Color','white','Menu','none','Units','normalized','Position',[0.05 0.05 0.9 0.9]);
text(0.5,0.5,[mat_1; mat_2],'Color','k','FontSize',12,'HorizontalAlignment','center','VerticalAlignment','middle')
axis off;
```